# VB.NET error "Expression is of type 'Attachments', which is not a collection type"

Tags: vb.net, foreach, collections

I want to read Attachments from outlook .msg file.
I copy the VB code from another solution I found here, but in "For Each att In msg.Attachments" loop, I get the error "Expression is of type 'Attachment', which is not a collection type".

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
Can you help me please?

```
Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strAttPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    strFilePath = "C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test\"
    strAttPath = "C:\Users\...\extracted attachment\"
    strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "<Doc Name>.msg")

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strFile)
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For Each att In msg.Attachments
                att.SaveAsFile(strAttPath & att.FileName)
            Next
        End If
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook types are provided via COM Interop. They predate .Net and don't know anything about providing .Net's `GetEnumerator()` method, which is how the `For Each` loop works. You will need to manually loop through by index.

Comment: I find that a little surprising since the .NET conventions are IIRC very similar to the COM conventions used for the pre-.NET VB `For Each`.  I wonder if this is something where you would get a different result depending on whether `Option Strict` is on, e.g. failure under strict because `GetEnumerator` isn't exposed by the known type, but success without because it's there for late binding.

Comment: Though maybe the problem is that even in a COM context they don't actually support enumeration.